# The normal-appearing question closed with irrelevant reason

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm asking about this queston: [Is this UPS Product safe to be around?](https://superuser.com/questions/1760973/is-this-ups-product-safe-to-be-around)

I don't understand why the question was closed. The reason is about shopping recommendations, while the question is not. It asks for explanation of the warning in the manual.

Since UPS is a standard computer accessory it could be on topic here. Some people consider this a "gray area", but I see the general consensus here is to allow questions about management of the UPS. For instance, [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13462/which-ups-related-questions-are-on-topic).

Comment: This is more of a chemistry and biology question combined with legal labelling to me. The UPS itself, how to use it and connect it to a computer is 100% on topic, but the long term health effects are far more about the person than about the device. Especially so when you consider that those warnings only apply to an extreme case where someone has basically misused the device to the point where those chemicals are leaking out and are causing the hazard that is warned about. Under normal use there is nearly zero risk of contact with those chemicals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well - its somewhat less than about it being about a UPS, and more about the [california proposition 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_California_Proposition_65) - in general, questions here are about the *use* of hardware and software, rather than legally required labelling IMO.